# Consider the initial value problem $y'' + 7y'+ 12y = 0, y(0) = 4.94, y'(0) = \beta$ where $\beta > 0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the initial value problem $y'' + 7y'+ 12y = 0, y(0) = 4.94, y'(0) = \beta$ where $\beta > 0$.

Determine the coordinates $t_m$  and $y_m$ of the maximum point of the solution as functions of $\beta$.

Determine of the behavior of $t_m$ and $y_m$ as beta $\to \infty$ .

I am unsure as to how to approach this problem. I can solve the problem with the initial conditions, however I don't know how to find the maximum points. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a linear differential equation, first look at the characteristic equation. In your case, the characteristic equation is
$$m^2+7m+12 = 0 \implies (m+3)(m+4) = 0 \implies m=-3 \text{ or }-4$$
Hence, the solution to the differential equation is of the form
$$y(x) = c_1 e^{-3x} + c_2 e^{-4x}$$
We are also given that $y'(x) = -3c_1e^{-3x} - 4c_2e^{-4x}$. Hence, $y'(0)= -3c_1-4c_2 = \beta$. Further, $y(0) = \alpha$, i.e., $c_1 + c_2 = \alpha$. This gives us $c_2 = -3\alpha - \beta$ and $c_1 = 4\alpha+\beta$. Hence, we have
$$y(x) = (4\alpha + \beta)e^{-3x} - (3\alpha+\beta)e^{-4x}$$
Maximum is attained when $y'(x) = 0$, i.e.,
$$-3c_1e^{-3x} - 4c_2e^{-4x} = 0 \implies e^x = -\dfrac{4c_2}{3c_1} = \dfrac{12\alpha+4\beta}{12\alpha+3\beta} = 1 + \dfrac{\beta}{12\alpha+3\beta}$$In your case, $\alpha = 4.94$.

For the behavior as $x \to \infty$, note that $e^{-3x}$ and $e^{-4x}$ both decay to zero as $x \to \infty$. Hence, $\lim_{x\to\infty}y(x) = 0$.